# Firefox Open a new tab instead of a pop window?

Tags: firefox, tabs, window

I found that in recent version of Firefox, there was add a setting called "Open new windows in a new tab instead".

When I keep it on, all the pop windows(Using javascript "window.open" function opened) opened in a new tab, which I realy need opened in a pop window(With settings like "menubar=no" and etc.). Some normal links with "target="_blank" attribute will open in new window if I keep it off.

So, is anyone here knows whether it's a bug or maybe I mistake someting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

I was having the same exact problem, but only with Firefox (3.*+) after a certain date and only on my Mac (Windows machines worked fine).  Finally, I used the guest account on my Mac and saw that Firefox worked properly, so I tried disabling all extensions, to no avail.  Finally, I manually searched through the about:config properties for anything that looked suspicious or non-default.  As it turns out, I think I must have installed an extension that tweaked the **`browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction`** property to 0 (instead of the default of 2) - once I changed it back, all was well.  See the following for a thorough explanation of this property - which seems to be unexposed through Firefox's other tab/popup/window UI options:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction

Answer (score 2):

For future searchers who find this question, there is a setting that you can toggle that opens all new windows in a new tab in Firefox.

Firefox Menu>Options>Tabs>Open new windows in a new tab instead - and un-check that check-box.

Switching between browsers for testing, I didn't realize there was that setting.

Comment: For me, I have that setting set in options, but for some reason Firefox is overriding it or ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean, but see the link below:

[Firefox Support / Knowledge Base / Options window - Tabs panel](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Options+window+-+Tabs+panel#wikiplugin_showfor1)

It writes:

> If you have chosen to open pages in new tabs, Firefox will ignore this optionpreference  and will open a new window from a link if the page author specified that the new window should have a specific size, because some pages can only be displayed correctly at a specific size.

I mean, Firefox **does not ignore** my preference when I open those links created by javascript "window.open" scripts.