# popup with reference from form text field - php

Tags: php, forms, popup

I have a php signup form. I have a text field named `username` ie, `<input type="text" name="username">` to enter username. I have a button next to it with value and name as `check`. I want to popup a small window when user click the check button. I just want the entered text (username) to get displayed in the popup window.

The key need is to transfer the data from this window to popup window.

How can I make this possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure what are your really wanted. I guess experimentX has a point. Anyway try this code. But first your calling page must be a php.

**PHP:**

```
<p>User Name is: <?php echo $_GET['userName']; ?> </p>
```

**HTML**

Forwarding value via URL

```
<form>
<p>
    <input type="text" name="userName" />
    <input type="button" value="check" onClick="window.open('popWindow.php?' + 'userName=' + this.form.userName.value, '_new')" />
</p>
</form>
```

Forwarding value via submit:

```
<form action="popWindow.php" target="_new" method="GET">
<p>
    <input type="text" name="userName" />
    <input type="submit" value="check" />
</p>
</form>
```

I hope this can help. If not please be more specific and provide more of your code.

Comment: Thank you @ace.. This works.. But it opens in a new tab in firefox.. Can u help me to make this work in a popup (seperate window) with fixed width and height?

Comment: This a browser settings see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788266/firefox-open-a-new-tab-instead-of-a-pop-window Then to change the settings http://qualitypoint.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-force-firefox-to-open-new-window.html